# ASP.Net application switch between login types (ADFS, Username/Password)

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, adfs

We have an web application written in .net 3.5 that we deploy for various clients and that uses a regular Forms login username/password.

We have a requirement to make it work with ADFS also. The issue is that we would like to be able to keep both login methods, and have one for some clients, and one for others, so we would like to keep most of it at a config level.

Exactly what would be the correct method to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it at the config level and choose your preferred localAuthenticationTypes.

In Windows Explorer, browse to C:\inetpub\adfs\ls (assuming that inetpub lives in C:)
Select web.config and Edit in Notepad

Find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+F

There are four lines below . Each line represents one of the local authentication types listed above.

Cut your preferred local authentication type (the entire line), and Paste it to the top of the list (under )

Save and Close the web.config file

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-local-authentication-type.aspx

Alternatively, you can configure the alternate ID in ADFS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configuring-alternate-login-id